# Xcode game crashes and points to SpriteNode saying "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xa001800"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite

There are a couple of SKNodes that are giving me this issue, I declare the nodes fairly standard such as

```
let face = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"final.png")// <- this is the line it points to
face.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width*0.5, y: self.frame.size.height*0.5)
face.xScale = 1
face.yScale = 1
addChild(face)
```

however when it comes time to load the sprite, my game crashes. I also tried a different approach such as:

```
let face = SKTexture(imageNamed: "final.png")// <- this is the line it points to
show = SKSpriteNode(texture: face)
show.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width*0.5, y: self.frame.size.height*0.5)
show.xScale = 1
show.yScale = 1
addChild(show)
```

still, the problem persists. The game crashes on my iDevice and xCode gives to error message. However it highlights the line where I reference my image and says: **EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xa001800**

Comment: Do you definitely have the file included in your project?

Comment: yeah I do, I have it both in the image.xcassets folder and in the project folder as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you've added your picture as an imageAsset, remove the ending of your png when you call it:

```
let face = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"final")// <- this is the line it points to
```

Comment: it still crashes whether I include the image extension or not.

Comment: Have you added it to your imageAssets and the name is also correct?

Comment: yeah, the name letter for letter accurate but for some reason it doesn't work properly

Comment: can there perhaps be an issue with the file? or maybe xCode?

Comment: are there pics for all three different sizes?

Comment: no only for one size, but on all the tutorials that I've seen over the months developers don't seem to utilize images for different sizes.  I didn't suspect that would be an issue

Comment: I've added larger versions of my pictures but the issue continues to persist. Funny how to app never ever will crash on the simulator but it'll crash on my iDevice, can the problem be with my iDevice rather than the game?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! turns out the problem was in my iDevice not the game, if anyone seems to run into a similar problem I suggest running the game on more than just one iDevice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image has the exact same name as the one in your assets folder because normally you don't need the .png extension. Like this:

```
let face = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"final")
```